# Assigning value to bool not givin expected result

Tags: objective-c, boolean

Following code:

```
usepassive = [agencydata valueForKey:@"passive"];
                NSLog(@"agencydata usepassive: %@",[agencydata valueForKey:@"passive"]);
                NSLog(@"vardata usepassive: %hhd",usepassive);
```

Produces this output:

```
2014-05-13 21:35:41.424 Stockuploader[957:303] agencydata usepassive: 1
2014-05-13 21:35:41.425 Stockuploader[957:303] vardata usepassive: 7
```

I would expect it to be 1 and 1, but it is 1 and 7.

`usepassive` is declared like this `BOOL usepassive;` in my .h file.

what is wrong?

Comment: `valueForKey:` returns an object, not a `BOOL`. Do you see any warnings when you compile? If so, fix them first.

Comment: And why are you using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`?

Comment: thats the point, it isnt giving me any warnings.. I have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: agencydata is a NSMutableDictionary. Am I not supposed to use valueForKey? its working fine for all other Keys. Its just this Boolean that is giving me headache.

Comment: What's really in `agencydata`? And what object is really being returned for the `passive` key?

Comment: The only way this isn't giving you warnings is if warnings are turned off!

Comment: You should only use `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` if you have a specific need to use key-value coding (KVC). Normally you always want to use `objectForKey:` and `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store `BOOL` objects in a dictionary (or other collections) without first wrapping it in an `NSNumber`. This means that when you get the value from the dictionary, you are getting the `NSNumber`. You need to convert this to `BOOL`.

You can do:

```
// Assuming usepasive is defined as BOOL
usepassive = [[agencydata objectForKey:@"passive"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"agencydata usepassive: %@", [agencydata objectForKey:@"passive"]); // logs the NSNumber
NSLog(@"vardata usepassive: %hhd", usepassive); // logs the BOOL
```

Also consider modern syntax:

```
usepassive = [agencydata[@"passive"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"agencydata usepassive: %@", agencydata[@"passive"]); // logs the NSNumber
NSLog(@"vardata usepassive: %hhd", usepassive); // logs the BOOL
```

Comment: Thank you very much! saving this into my prefs.

Comment: Also, make sure you haven't turned off warnings. The code you posted should have given you some sort of warning for trying to assign an `id` to a `BOOL`.

Comment: Warnings are active, I get them all the time, but this one did not give any warning at all... Dont know why.

Comment: Strange. I just checked and I don't get a warning either.

Comment: At least that means that i am not crazy.. :D Thanks again! You were really helpful!